# Required readings for courses on the Gospels at the Westminster Theological Seminary

Tags: gospels, resource-request, biblical-theology, seminary

I want to learn Biblical Theology by myself, but I don’t know the appropriate textbook to start. Though I’m not a student from Westminster Theological Seminary, I still want to read what students there read. So, I want to know something about the required readings for courses on the Gospels at the Westminster Theological  Seminary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Westminster Theological Seminary](https://www.wts.edu/) used to provide a [recommended reading list](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104213757/http://www.wts.edu/becoming/whywestminster/recommendedreading.html) for prospective students, compiled by their faculty, administration, and alumni.  It included a book list for [**New Testament**](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104213757/http://www.wts.edu/becoming/whywestminster/recommendedreading.html#New%20Testament) as well as a book list for [**Biblical Theology and Hermeneutics**](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104213757/http://www.wts.edu/becoming/whywestminster/recommendedreading.html#BT%20&%20Hermeneutics).  Kevin Sheth created a [goodreads.com list](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/98620.Westminster_Theological_Seminary_Recommended_Reading) for most of the books.

Their [Westminster Bookstore website](https://www.wtsbooks.com/) has [a list of textbooks](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/wts-textbooks) grouped by courses, which should include what you are looking for (especially NT 211 and NT 705):

- [BT 101](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/online-bt-101-bible-survey): Bible Survey
- [BT 173](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/online-bt-173-principles-of-biblical-interpretation) : Principles of Biblical Interpretation
- [NT 111](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/nt-111-new-testament-introduction-briones) : New Testament Introduction (NT 101 and NT 103 combined)
- [NT 123](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/online-nt-123-hermeneutics) : Hermeneutics
- [NT 211](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/w3-textbooksfall-nt-211-gospels-crowe) : Gospels
- [NT 705](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/nt-705-gospel-of-mark-crowe) : Gospel of Mark
- [NT 921](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/nt921-readings-in-nt-intro-and-theology-crowe) : Readings in NT Intro and Theology
- [ST 605/905](https://www.wtsbooks.com/collections/st-605-905-systematic-theology-biblical-theology-and-theological-method-gamble) : Systematic Theology, Biblical Theology, and Theological Method

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @GalleVan Welcome to C.SE.  If this answers your question, you can then "Accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark.  Looking forward for your future questions !